# как сделать чтобы последний массив был без запятой?

Tags: php

Вывожу массив так, как сделать чтобы последний массив был без ', '  ?

```
        <?php

// переменные
$tematiki_kanalov = get_field('tematiki_kanalov');



// проверка
if( $tematiki_kanalov ): ?>

    <?php foreach( $tematiki_kanalov as $tematika ): ?>
<?php echo '' . $tematika['label'] . ', ' ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: За такой codestyle пальчики все же стоит отрубить... я бы предложил обрезать последний символ строки, но так как вы все сразу выводите... предлагаю добавить проверку, должен ли там быть этот символ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
 $labels = [];
 foreach( $tematiki_kanalov as $tematika ):
   $labels[] = $tematika['label'];
 endforeach;
 echo implode(', ', $labels);
?>
```

Comment: `implode(', ', array_column(...., 'label'))`